# Ruby on Rails: Handle domain and subdomain level cookies simultaneosly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, dns, subdomain

In an environment where a very big online application/web is divided into subdomains:

- `app1.mydomain.com`
- `app2.mydomain.com`

Each app is able to handle its subdomain session cookie.

However, in order to mantain certain data live through all apps, like session provider and account information in a multi-single-sign-on environment, it would be useful to also store/access session cookies at a domain level:

- `mydomain.com`

What would be the best approach to handle simultaneously domain level and subdomain session cookies in Ruby on Rails? One issue would also be that this domain level cookie should be encrypted with the same hash across all applications/subdomains, which can be done, but doesn't fully integrate with Rails session design, unless all application share their secret token.

Best I could think of is use Rails default session handler for subdomain cookies, and create manually a domain level cookie handler, however it would be cool to be able to use `session` and `domain_session` as it is designed to be used more easily, though this is not a common issue.

Comment: Have you considered an authentication as a service approach instead where the subdomain apps query the service api (with a token) to get this information instead of shared cookie? I would worry about the tight couplings you're making here.

Comment: already using an authentication as a service approach (a Single Sign On). Problem is we are now required to implement multiple SSO, including non-standard SSO, and when switching we would not know which SSO the user has logged into.